# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger in Weblogic 12.2.1.4.0 while upgrading from 12.2.1.0.0

Tags: java, slf4j, weblogic12c

I am upgrading weblogic from 12.2.1.0.0 to 12.2.1.4.0. Weblogic upgradation is successfull. But when I am going to start up server, deployment is failed. Below is full error trace. I am attaching screenshot of Admin console which shows failed state. Can you please help me to overcome this issue? [Weblogic Admin Console with failed deployment state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hwYk.png)

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextStateInParallel(StateMachineDriver.java:144)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.parallelPrepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:46)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:75)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:166)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:41)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:193)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionAppInternal(AppTransition.java:32)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:138)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:153)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:363)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:232)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:786)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
```